# Android studio new project different window

Tags: android, project

I update my Android studio in 3.1.1. and when I tried to make a new project, it open a diffent window, not the usual..

[image]

Also, when I open an existing project, on .xml files, there was no "design" option on the bottom..

Is there anyone who can help me to fix it??
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the Android plugin is disabled in your Android Studio. You need to enable it from **Preferences -> Plugins**, then search for Android Support and enable it like the following image:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't let me save the changes!! Any ideas??

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yVyQD_8IEn5uqr4uu_NFa_mFUcSLOPF_

Comment: Looks like your Android studio installation is corrupted or you don't have permission to change the Android Studio preference which is unlikely.

Comment: You think it would be better to uninstall and install again the program??

Comment: I reinstall the program but still have the same problem.. any idea??